# Linked plusminus notation $\pm$

Tags: notation

Given an expression with multiple $\pm$ where some of the $\pm$ have to behave the same. What is the correct notation?

Colours?

$$1 \color{red}\pm (x \color{red} \pm 3) \pm 4$$ Here the two red $\pm$ must either both be $+$ or both be $-$ and the black $\pm$ can behave independently. Using colours seems fairly self-explanatory but cannot then be printed in black and white.

Variables?

$$1 \pm_{1} (x \ \pm_{1} 3) \pm 4$$

Attaching a variable or number to the plus-minus looks a bit messy and could be misread:

Any suggestions / most widely used notation would be appreciated.

Comment: $1+c_1(x+3c_1)+4c_2$ where $c_1,c_2\in\{-1,1\}$

Comment: @JMoravitz that's a neat way to do it. Is that standard or just a suggestion?

Comment: A suggestion, but this happens often enough in combinatorial contexts and linear algebra that I've certainly seen this used before

Comment: There's no standard for what you are trying to describe, because this situation is quite uncommon. To me, JMoravitz's way is the most efficient.

Comment: In a couple posts online I've used subsccripted numbers as suggested in the question post, along with an explanation about what I'm doing. If I need linked symbols like this I generally have a bunch of variables around and I'd rather not introduce more variables if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no common or standard notation which conveys the idea in the question.  Because there is a lack of such notation, I would suggest that if new notation is going to be introduced, then it should be very clearly defined somewhere before it is used.  I would also strongly suggest that color not be used—not all journals print in color, colorblindness is a thing, etc.  The notation $\pm_1$, $\pm_2$, etc. might work, though I find it unaesthetic (personally).

As I see it, there are two pre-existing and commonly used notations which are relevant:

1. The symbols $\pm$ and $\mp$ can be used.  This is somewhat limited:  in the expression $1 \pm (x \pm 3) \pm 4$, it is not clear if the three signs must be the same or can be different; while in the expression $1 \pm (x \pm 3) \mp 4$ it must be the case that the first two signs are the same, and the third is different.  However, there are contexts in which $\pm$ and $\mp$ are very useful.
2. Dummy variables may be used.  For example, as noted in the comments by  JMoravitz, it would be very reasonable to write
   $$ 1 + c_1(x + 3 c_1) + 4 c_2, \qquad c_1, c_2 \in \{\pm 1\}. $$
   That is, instead of subscripting the operators, introduce new variables, and subscript them.  One could go so far as to introduce a class of dummy variables towards the beginning of a paper, e.g.

   > The variables $s_i$ will be used throughout to indicate the sign of a term.  As such, $s_i \in \{\pm 1\}$ for any index $i$.  For example,
   >   $$ 1 + s_1(x+3s_1) + 4s_2 $$
   >   expands to
   >   $$ 1 + (x+3) - 4,
   > \quad 1 + (x+3) + 4,
   > \quad 1 - (x-3) - 4,
   > \quad\text{or}\quad
   > 1 - (x-3) + 4. $$

Comment: Just a nitpick: I think your example at the end would expand to all four of: $1+(x+3)+4$, $1-(x-3)+4$, $1+(x+3)+4$, $1-(x-3)-4$.

Comment: @MarkS. Indeed.  I had assumed that $s_1 \ne s_2$.  Thanks.